# url rewriting using .htaccess for different urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url, bluehost

I'm trying to create clean urls using .htaccess on my website i have this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /full_posts.php?permalink=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/$ /search.php?category=$1 [L]
```

the first one is working correctly but the second one is not working, I'm writing both one after another. please help!

Comment: _not working_; how? Which page are you accessing? What error is shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules you are looking for are:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /full_posts.php?permalink=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/?$ /search.php?category=$1 [L]
```

I have made the trailing slash optoinal in both the cases.

You can test your rules on:
http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: i got it now, i have not added that slash at the end. thanks

Comment: sir, how to make the last forward slash as optional

Comment: To make the trailing slash optional you can put a questionmark before it.

  

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /full_posts.php?permalink=$1 [L]` and 
    `RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/?$ /search.php?category=$1 [L]`

Comment: ok, i have added .html instead of the slash, i want to know which on is better

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. I see no use for .html on a site... it just makes the URL a bit harder to type for the users. I would suggest that you skip it!

Also try to be consistent with urls so that search engines doesnt end up finding duplicate content. Use canonical URLs!

Comment: @Fabian Please, modify your answer to contain what was the solution for the problem. This is not a real answer this way.